# How do i create in a table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Whenever I go to sql in phpmyadmin to create a table, I put this code in:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `sign_up_date` date NOT NULL,
      `activated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

it says:`#1046 - No database selected` 
but when I put:

```
CREATE DATABASE data;
USE data;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `sign_up_date` date NOT NULL,
      `activated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

it says that it could not create the database?

Comment: "it says that it could not create the database?" What was the actual error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Choose an existing Database or create a new Database.

[image: Step 1:]

Step 2: Choose the SQL tab and add your code to create a table.
[image: Step 2:]

Comment: Can you please post those images here? Because if for some reason those images get deleted, you answer becomes worthless, and we don't want that to happen.

Comment: Worthless? It's two clicks that are both described in text too.

Answer (score 1):

One server can contain multiple databases. If you login into PHPMyAdmin, you choose a server to login to. After you've logged in, you have to select your database to be able to make changes to it.

So you don't need to create a database. You just need to select it. You can do that with the `USE <databasename>` statement, or though the PHPMyAdmin interface. In your second snippet, you already used have the `USE` statement. You just need to remove the `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

Same goes for creating the table, by the way. PHPMyAdmin provides an interface to add a table field by field without having to write the SQL for it. Although it can't hurt to know the syntax, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have got your sql statement, then just go to
 phpMyAdmin > login (if there is need for it) > select database you want to use, 
find it in Right Hand Side , example 'test'. tehn simply just find the
 tab named sql and click it, after that just paste your statements